# Launch file on local file server from web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, activex, webdav

Given an ASP.NET MVC intranet web app, how can I give users access to files located on a shared (mapped) drive? I don't want the browser to download a copy, I want to emulate the user navigating to the drive and opening the file.

I understand that there are security risks, and that this is not a simple task. I've considered webdav, and activex, and worst case scenario in-browser editing. BUT, I'd like to think there's a way to accomplish this.

Thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you asking how to create a URI to a file in a shared folder? Like `\\servername\foldername\file.docx` or `file://dnsname/foldername/file.docx`? That's just a [File URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Comment: mason, when I click on a URI the browser downloads a copy of that file. I want to open that file from its location, and not a copy.

Comment: Does the user have the shared folder that the file is in already mapped to a drive letter?

Comment: Yes, all users 100% have the shared folder and access to the files.

Comment: Then read the link I provided in my first comment, which shows the syntax for the URI for a drive letter. Then give the user a hyperlink to click `<a href="file:///z:/path/to/the%20file.txt">Click here to open the file</a>`, obviously replacing Z with the driver letter you mapped the shared folder to.

Comment: Nope. A well formed link initiates a download of the file.

Comment: What if you link to the folder that the file is in?

Comment: Nothing happens when linking to the folder.